# How to trigger an event from child view to parent view in backbonejs and requirejs

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

I have a parentview which dynamically creates a child view and I have triggered an event from child view to parent view and I am passing the model of the child view to parent view with some properties set. now in the parent view i have to take the model and add to collection. here is my code
child view trigger code

```
$(this.el).trigger('added', this.model);
```

parentview event

```
events: {
            "added": "addNewAttribute"
        },
    addNewAttribute: function (model) {
        console.log(model);
        this.collection.add(model);
        console.log(this.collection);
    }
```

console.log returns undefined. can someone let me know how to pass the model back to parent view?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be off base but I'd guess that the child view did not do binding for the function that contains this code:

```
$(this.el).trigger('added', this.model);
```

As a result when you get into the function that code is in, "this" doesn't point to the child view, it points to some DOM object or something. Then this.model doesn't point to what you expect.

For example:

```
initialize : function () {
  _.bindAll(this, "addFunction");
}

addFunction : function () {
  $(this.el).trigger('added', this.model);
}
```

Comment: Hi John when i print out console.log(model); in addNewAttribute function im getting something like this f.Event instead of actual model what do you think im missing ? i have put _bindAll in my code as u mentioned.

Comment: @Kishore I think it would help a lot if we could see more of the client view's code to figure out what might be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Just faced the same problem!

The thing is that the parent function takes as first parameter the event
and the trigger function passes variables as an array.
so the code should be like:

```
$(this.el).trigger('added', [this.model]);
```

parentview event:

```
events: {
    "added": "addNewAttribute"
},
addNewAttribute: function (event,model) {
    console.log(model);
    this.collection.add(model);
    console.log(this.collection);
}
```

this worked for me.