# Backbone - Trigger the parent view event from child view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to trigger the event of parent view from its child view. But it seems that the parent view's event did not gets triggered.

Following is the sample for my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.1.4/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.3.3/backbone-min.js"></script>

    <script>

    MySubView = Backbone.View.extend({
        id : "MySubView",

        initialize: function() {
          console.log("pro1");

          this.trigger("testGo", "test");
        }
    });

    MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
        id : "MyView",

        initialize: function() {
          console.log("pro");
          this.subview = new MySubView();
          this.subview.listenTo("testGo", this.addFoo, this);
        },

        addFoo: function() {
          console.log("ok");
          alert("ok");
        }
  });

  new MyView();

</script>

</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to get hint from many solutions found via google search, but it seems I am got struck somewhere. Some of the options which I found are :

1/ [How to trigger an event from child view to parent view in backbonejs and requirejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11056001/how-to-trigger-an-event-from-child-view-to-parent-view-in-backbonejs-and-require)

2/ [Backbone: How to trigger methods in a parent view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16931120/backbone-how-to-trigger-methods-in-a-parent-view)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are using listenTo wrong.

```
anObject.listenTo(anotherObject, 'forSomeEvent', function () { console.log('do something'); });
```

So, in your case, you should do it like this:

```
 MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
        id : "MyView",

        initialize: function() {
          console.log("pro");
          this.subview = new MySubView();
          this.listenTo(this.subview, 'testGo', this.addFoo);
        },

        addFoo: function() {
          console.log("ok");
          alert("ok");
        }
  });
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: i added the code to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v0k1auwa/) with the suggestion provided by you. but still some issue is faced. also i checked the doc , you are correct. i will check more on it tomorrow. anyway thanks.

Comment: @turtle hi, I am facing the same issue, may I know that have you solve the problem, in my case, trigger can be done from parent view to child view, but not the inverse way as your post

Answer (score 2):

Your `listenTo` usage is slightly off

The signature is `object.listenTo(otherObject, event, callback)` so you want something like:

```
this.listenTo(this.subview, "testGo", this.addFoo);
```

Which tells `this` to listen to `this.subview` for the event `testGo` and call `this.addFoo` when the event is triggered

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
this.listenTo(this.subview, "testGo",this.addFoo);
```

signature:

```
     object.listenTo(other, event, callback)
```

Comment: i added the code to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v0k1auwa/) with the suggestion provided by you. but still some issue is faced.i will check more on it tomorrow. anyway thanks.

Comment: This example would be even more helpful with some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Triggering event:

```
Backbone.Events.trigger('<eventname>', {data1 to be passed with event},  {data2 to be passed with event}...);
```

Listener:

```
Backbone.Events.bind('<eventname>', callback, context);
```